# ReactJs trying to create a filter list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create an filter list which filter the list on typed input. But don't know why the if statement is not working.

Here is the function I wrote: `

```
filterList (event) {
    var updatedList = this.props.array; 
    var filterText = this.state.text;
    updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(item){
      console.log(filterText);
      if(item.name === filterText){
        console.log('check', item.name);
      }
    });
```

Can someone help me out on this here is a link to my codepen: [LINK](http://codepen.io/smgjrein/pen/ALbVyo)

Comment: Because you set a local variable to the filtered array, you don't return it, you don't update the state, you filter it then throw it away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter needs to update the array in the component state to force a re-render. You don't update props to force a re-render, props are more for initial data, or consistent data, which can be updated from the top level.

Change the handle function to pass the text to the filterList function, and return the result

```
handleChange(event) {
  var array = this.filterList(event.target.value);
  this.setState({ text: event.target.value, array: array });
},

filterList (filterText) {
  var updatedList = this.props.array;
  return updatedList.filter(function(item){
    return item.name === filterText;
  });
}
```

Update getInitialState to use the props:

```
getInitialState() {
  return { text:'', array: this.props.array};
}
```

Then use the state instead of props in your render:

```
var arrayComponents = this.state.array.map(function(photo) {
     return <li className="photo photo-name">{photo.name} <img className="photo" src={photo.link}/></li>;
})
```

Comment: Thanks this works you maybe got a solution to filter on seperate letters? Now it only filters when whole name matches the input

Comment: Sure. Sorry for late reply. You simply need to change the equals comparison. If you want the text to be based on what it starts with. So `Phot` matches, but `oto` does not, use a regular rexpression. `return new RegExp('^' + filterText).test(item.name)`. If you just want to match if the text is contained, can do: `return item.name.indexOf(filterText) !== -1`.

Answer (score 1):

First, when I run your codepen example, I'm not seeing any errors indicating that `this.state.text` is undefined. It's not filtering anything, but it is displaying the value of `this.state.text`. So the issue is not quite what your question suggests it is...

So how to we get this thing filtering? Basically, the idea with ReactJS components is that everything related to the current state of your component should be in `this.state`, and any decisions about what to display based on that state should be in the `render` method. And keep in mind that any time you change the state using the `setState` method, it's going to trigger a re-rendering of your component.

With that in mind, I'd set things up like this:

1. your component receives a list of photos via the `array` prop (I'd probably call it something else, since it's not very descriptive and it's awfully close to a reserved word in Javascript)
2. the state for the component has one value: `text` (again, not very descriptive)
3. the component has a `handleChange` handler for the input element. I would connect this to the `onChange` handler for the input element - don't worry, it will be called every time the value in the input element changes. This should be the only event handler on the input element and all it should do is call `this.setState({ text: event.target.value });`
4. do the list filtering **in the render method**. The key here is that you don't need to keep a filtered list of your photos - all you're doing with it is rendering it, so do it only when you need to (or rather, when React thinks you need to and calls the `render` method). So your render method will look something like this:

   ```
   render() {
       var myFilteredList = this.props.array.filter(function(item){
           console.log(filterText);
           if(item.name === filterText){
               console.log('check', item.name);
               return true;
           }

           return false;
       });

       var arrayComponents = myFilteredList.map(function(photo) {
           return <li className="photo photo-name">{photo.name} <img className="photo" src={photo.link}/></li>;
       });

       return (
       <div>
           <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
           <p>{this.state.text}</p>
           <input type="text"  onKeyUp={this.handleChange} />
           <ul>
               {arrayComponents}
           </ul>
       </div>
       );
   }
   ```

That's it. This has a couple of advantages:

1. it keeps it simple - don't maintain any state for the component outside of `this.state` and if you only need it for rendering, don't maintain it at all.
2. it keeps your code cleaner - the way I've approached it, your component has only two methods: `handleChange` and `render`
3. it (should be) more performant - React is pretty good at deciding when to render based on state changes, and it tends to be better when components have minimal state. (I say "should be" simply because I haven't tested it out at all).